# iter(callable, sentinel) form on byte array

Tags: python, iterator, generator, callable

I am using an API that returns messages terminated by a \x04 (end of transmission) byte. I would like to catch this byte in a nice way. This is the code I wrote:

```
# Only works if buffer size is 1 byte
read = lambda: self._sslsocket.recv(1)

response = b''
for data_buffer in iter(read, b'\x04'):
    response += data_buffer
```

I would like to make this solution work with arbritrary buffer size. Is there an way to do so without crippling performance, or should I use a generator/classic while True with recv(1024)?

Comment: It may be because I'm not an expert at socket programming, but I'm not sure I understand what the issue is with larger buffer sizes. Is your concern that getting only one byte at a time is slow, and you're rather get a bunch, then somehow break them down into a one-byte-at-a-time stream in your own code? Or is there some larger issue (like a `'\x04'` byte getting lost in the middle of a larger string)?

Comment: Yes to the former. My issue is with getting one byte at a time with socket.recv(1), because that would make one system call for each byte. I fear this would be slower than simply getting a larger buffer, then processing that buffer in my code.

For the latter concern, that is not my problem but the API's if it happens, since its specificiation says that it does not return `'\x04'` bytes other than at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could code it either of the two following ways:

```
def read(bufsize):
    return lambda: self._sslsocket.recv(bufsize)
```

or more succinctly as:

```
read = lambda bufsize: lambda: self._sslsocket.recv(bufsize)
```

Sample usage:

```
response = b''
for data_buffer in iter(read(1), b'\x04'):
    response += data_buffer
```

Basically these turn the local `read()` function into a very specialized decorator (function that returns a function).

Comment: I think the OP's concern is only reading a byte at a time; you're defining a more general function that is used to read one byte at a time.

Comment: @chepner: I disagree about what the OP's concern is and about what you're claiming my answer does. The `read()` function that gets defined can be used to read any number of bytes at a time by passing it a different `bufsize` argument.